# Toolbar text dimmed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I'm having a problem trying to get my toolbar to look like the one in Play Store.

This is how it looks, notice the text is not dimmed, and it's a bright white color: http://prntscr.com/4zlttl

And this is how it looks in my app: http://prntscr.com/4zlubl

Notice how in my app the text is dimmed, as well as the toolbar, while in the Play Store, the toolbar is dimmed but the text isn't.

Does anyone know how do I get this look?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: this is the same issues I'm having - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543797/remove-navigationdrawer-s-shadow-on-toolbar

Comment: Toolbar.. As in ActionBar? Dimmed.. As in different color is used?

Comment: Toolbar as in toolbar :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html And it's not a different color, it just has a shadow over it, not sure how to remove it.

Comment: Are you setting the correct theme for your app? In this case you should inherit from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar so that your colours are properly set for a dark background.

Comment: No, that didn't work, the title color changed to black, but it still dims the text, like it has a shadow over it.

Comment: In the screenshot, is that an open navigation drawer? Is your Toolbar inside of a DrawerLayout?

Comment: Yes, both screenshots show an open navigation drawer. And yes, my toolbar is inside of the drawer layout :)

Comment: Have you tried moving your Toolbar out of your DrawerLayout? By default, all content under an open drawer (including your Toolbar) gets darkened.

Comment: It worked! I thought the drawer layout had to be root layout :). Put your comment as an answer so I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your Toolbar style.

Define your Toolbar and set a style and a theme.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"/>
```

With the theme you can customize your UI elements inside:

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>
```

With the style you can customize for example the background color.

```
<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I still get the drawer shadow over the toolbar :(.

Comment: In this case you have to move the Toolbar outside the Drawer layout.